# Android change ToggleButton status - TextView or other android.widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using GCM and in the onRegistered method after the call to my server i've to change the state of the toggleButton in the AppSettings Activity

```
//called when i click the toggleButton
    public void onPushStateButtonClicked(View view) {
                // controllo se il bottone è su on
                boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
                PushClientService p = new PushClientService();
                if (on) {
                    savePushStateButton(true);
                    // se il bottone  in impostazioni è settato ad on registro il dispositivo
                    p.pushService(this);
                }else if(!on) {
                    savePushStateButton(false);
                    // se il bottone  in impostazioni è settato ad on cancello il dispositivo
                    //nel caso sia il primo accesso essendo il bottone a false di default preveniamo l'eccezione
                    try{    
                        GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
                    }catch(IllegalArgumentException iAE){
                        Log.e("Errore:","stai cercando di cancellate un device non registrato");
                    }
                }
            }
```

in the other class GCMIntentService

```
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
            Log.d("onRegistered", getString(R.string.gcm_registered));
            boolean myServerRegistration=ServerUtilities.customRegistration(context, registrationId);
            if(!myServerRegistration){
                // Errore sulla registrazione sul server, deregistro il device
                GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                **//change the state of the ToggleButton**

            }
        }
```

I want to set its value to false by another simple class where i've the context, it's possible? alternatively can i refresh an activity?

tnks for the response!

Comment: yes possible you will need to show some relevant code. you can do it by sending toggle instance to non Activity class or by passing Activity instance to non Activity class instead of Context and also declare ToggleButton instance as class field instead of method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've resolved myself
this is the code in the activity

```
// Set AppSettings object into GCMIntentService
        GCMIntentService.setActivityMain(AppSettings.this);
```

and this is in the GCMIntent class:

```
protected static AppSettings activityMain;

public static void setActivityMain(AppSettings a){
        activityMain = a;
    }
// run on UI thread
public void changePushStateButtonStatus(){

    activityMain.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activityMain.pushStateButton.setChecked(false);    
        }
    });
}


protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        Log.d("onRegistered", getString(R.string.gcm_registered));
        boolean myServerRegistration=ServerUtilities.customRegistration(context, registrationId);
        if(!myServerRegistration){
            // Error on our server registration, unregister the device
            GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
            // Save on sharedPreference the button status
            savePushStateButton(false);
            // Start a thread on UI to change the button status
            changePushStateButtonStatus();
        }
    }
```